# Dynamically building a menu

Tags: java, swing, menu, jtree

Currently my program has a `JTree` menu that is built dynamically. I pass the menu builder an object which describes it's path with an array of strings where each element represents a node, the final node is then set up to call a method of that object. A new node will only be created if it doesn't already exist otherwise the submenus are checked and the whole process is repeated.

I am trying to switch this to a `JMenu` system instead of a tree but I am having some issues.

So for example, the array of strings look something like:

```
["New", "Job", "Item A"]
["New", "Job", "Item B"]
["New", "Search", "Item C"]
```

This will then create a tree like:

```
┬ New
├──┬ Job
│  ├── Item A
│  └── Item B
└──┬ Search
   └── Item C
```

Now the problem I am having is I cannot tell if a submenu already exists with a `JMenu`. How can I check if a sub menu with desired name already exists?

Here is an example of how I build the `JTree`:

```
    String[] nodeNames = pane.getNodeDirectory();
    MenuTreeNode targetNode = root;
    int i = 0;

    if(targetNode.getChildCount() > 0) {
        //Search for the first node that doesn't exist in the pane's directory
        for(; i < nodeNames.length; ++i) {
            Enumeration e = targetNode.children();

            while(e.hasMoreElements()) {
                MenuTreeNode node = (MenuTreeNode)e.nextElement(); 

                if(node.getName().equals(nodeNames[i])) {
                    targetNode = node;
                    break;
                }
            }

            //We've been over all the children and none matched so we need
            //to build the rest of the directory.
            if(!e.hasMoreElements()) {
                ++i;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    //Build the remainder of the pane's directory
    for(; i < nodeNames.length; ++i) {
        MenuTreeNode currentNode = new MenuTreeNode(nodeNames[i]);

        targetNode.add(currentNode);
        targetNode = currentNode;
    }

    targetNode.setContentPane(pane);

    model.nodeStructureChanged(root);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can mix some different method calls and type checking to accomplish this task.

The following code dynamically builds the menu, discarding duplicates.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // just example input
    String[][] menuHierarchies = {
            {"New", "Job", "Item A"},
            {"New", "Job", "Item B"}, 
            {"New", "Search", "Item C"},
            {"New", "Item D"},
            {"Other", "Item E"},
            {"New", "Job", "Item B"}, 
            {"Other", "Job", "Item B"}
    };

    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();

    // relevant code from here. It builds the menu removing redundancies
    for (int rootIndex = 0; rootIndex < menuHierarchies.length; ++rootIndex) {
        JMenu parentMenu = null;

        for(int menuLevel = 0; menuLevel < menuHierarchies[rootIndex].length; ++menuLevel) {
            // if it is root menu
            if (menuLevel == 0) {
                // checks if the root menu already exists 
                for (int i = 0; i < menuBar.getMenuCount(); ++i) {
                    if (menuBar.getMenu(i).getText().equals(menuHierarchies[rootIndex][menuLevel])) {
                        parentMenu = menuBar.getMenu(i);
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (parentMenu == null) {
                    parentMenu = new JMenu(menuHierarchies[rootIndex][menuLevel]);
                    menuBar.add(parentMenu);
                }
            } else if (menuLevel < menuHierarchies[rootIndex].length - 1) { // if it is a non-leaf (and, of course, not a root menu)
                Component[] menuComponents = parentMenu.getMenuComponents();
                JMenu currentMenu = null;

                // checks if the menu already exists 
                for (Component component : menuComponents) {
                    if (component instanceof JMenu) {
                        if (((JMenu) component).getText().equals(menuHierarchies[rootIndex][menuLevel])) {
                            currentMenu = (JMenu) component;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (currentMenu == null) {
                    currentMenu = new JMenu(menuHierarchies[rootIndex][menuLevel]);
                    parentMenu.add(currentMenu);
                }

                parentMenu = currentMenu;
            } else { // if it is a leaf
                Component[] menuComponents = parentMenu.getMenuComponents();
                JMenuItem currentItem = null;

                for (Component component : menuComponents) {
                    if (component instanceof JMenuItem) {
                        if (((JMenuItem) component).getText().equals(menuHierarchies[rootIndex][menuLevel])) {
                            currentItem = (JMenuItem) component;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (currentItem == null) {
                    parentMenu.add(new JMenuItem(menuHierarchies[rootIndex][menuLevel]));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The following methods prints the menu hierarchy built, for testing purposes:

```
private static void printMenu(JMenuBar menuBar) {
    for (int i = 0; i < menuBar.getMenuCount(); ++i) {
        printMenu(menuBar.getMenu(i), 0);
    }
}

private static void printMenu(JMenuItem menuItem, int level) {
    for (int i = 0; i < level; ++i) {
        System.out.print("\t");
    }

    System.out.println("\\" + menuItem.getText());

    if (menuItem instanceof JMenu) {
        JMenu menu = (JMenu) menuItem;

        Component[] menuComponents = menu.getMenuComponents();

        for (Component component : menuComponents) {
            if (component instanceof JMenuItem) {
                printMenu((JMenuItem) component, level+1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is pretty much what I now have after testing my attempt some more. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've come up with this. It's not been exhaustively tested but it appears to work.

The way to get the name of a menu or menu item is through the `Accessible` interface. I make the assumption that all branches will be of type `JMenu`. I'm not sure how safe of an assumption that is.

```
    String[] nodeNames = pane.getNodeDirectory();
    JMenu currentMenu = null;
    int i = 0;

    for(int m = 0; m < menuBar.getMenuCount(); ++m) {
        String name = menuBar.getMenu(m).getAccessibleContext().getAccessibleName();

        if(name.equals(nodeNames[i])) {
            currentMenu = menuBar.getMenu(m);
            break;
        }
    }

    ++i;

    if(currentMenu != null && currentMenu.getMenuComponentCount() > 0) {
        boolean startBuild = false;

        //Find the first non existant child
        for(; i < nodeNames.length; ++i) {
            for(int j = 0; j < currentMenu.getMenuComponentCount(); ++j) {

                Component c = currentMenu.getMenuComponent(j);

                //If we're not at the leaf node search for a JMenu and if it
                //has the correct name set it as the current menu and move
                //onto the next node.
                if(i < nodeNames.length - 1 && c instanceof JMenu) {
                    String name = ((Accessible)c).getAccessibleContext().getAccessibleName();

                    if(name.equals(nodeNames[i])) {
                        currentMenu = (JMenu)c;
                        break;
                    }
                //If we're at the leaf node search for a JMenuItem to make
                //sure the requested item doesn't already exist
                } else if(i == nodeNames.length  - 1 && c instanceof JMenuItem) {
                    String name = ((Accessible)c).getAccessibleContext().getAccessibleName();

                    if(name.equals(nodeNames[i])) {
                        return;
                    }
                }

                //If we've reached the last component without finding an
                //appropriate item start building the menu
                if(j == currentMenu.getMenuComponentCount() - 1) {
                    startBuild = true;
                }
            }

            if(startBuild) {
                break;
            }
        }
    } else if(currentMenu == null) {
        currentMenu = new JMenu(nodeNames[i]);
        menuBar.add(currentMenu);
    }

    //Continue the loop from where we left off but this time making the
    //missing nodes instead of searching for existing nodes.
    for(; i < nodeNames.length - 1; ++i) {
        JMenu newMenu = new JMenu(nodeNames[i]);

        currentMenu.add(newMenu);
        currentMenu = newMenu;
    }

    JMenuItem item = new JMenuItem(nodeNames[nodeNames.length - 1]);
    item.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            pane.giveFocus();
        }
    });

    currentMenu.add(item);
```